# Smart way of plotting multiple curves out of one matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a matrix like this:

```
4.4367    4.5733    4.7127    4.8550    5.0000
0.0202    0.0151    0.0101    0.0050         0
4.4367    4.5733    4.7127    4.8550    5.0000
0.0188    0.0143    0.0097    0.0050         0
4.4367    4.5733    4.7127    4.8550    5.0000
0.0190    0.0144    0.0098    0.0050         0
4.4367    4.5733    4.7127    4.8550    5.0000
0.0191    0.0145    0.0098    0.0050         0
4.4367    4.5733    4.7127    4.8550    5.0000
0.0193    0.0146    0.0099    0.0050         0
4.4367    4.5733    4.7127    4.8550    5.0000
0.0195    0.0147    0.0099    0.0050         0
4.4367    4.5733    4.7127    4.8550    5.0000
0.0196    0.0148    0.0100    0.0050         0
4.4367    4.5733    4.7127    4.8550    5.0000
0.0198    0.0149    0.0100    0.0050         0
4.4367    4.5733    4.7127    4.8550    5.0000
0.0200    0.0150    0.0101    0.0050         0
4.4367    4.5733    4.7127    4.8550    5.0000
0.0202    0.0151    0.0101    0.0050         0
```

There are 20 rows, I want to plot 10 curves out of these, I know I
can do it like this:

plot(x1, x2, x3, x4, ...)

but it's tedious, is there any smart way of doing this?

Comment: Which "ten curves" - you want to plot row 1 vs row 2, row 3 vs row 4?

Comment: yes, 1 vs 2, 3 vs 4, 5, vs 6 etc

Comment: Are all the odd numbered rows equal?

Comment: Yes, in this case they are, but not always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `A` = your matrix with 20 rows and an arbitrary number of columns:

```
x = A(1:2:end,:);
y = A(2:2:end,:);
plot(x',y');
```

Answer (score 0):

[I just saw the other (much better) answer, a bug in the mobile app I guess]
This might be what your looking for:

```
s='plot(x1';
for i=2:20
s=strcat([s ',x' num2str(i)]);
eval(strcat(s,')'));
```

Or some variation of it..